# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' (python 2.7)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling, quantile

I have a dataframe `t_unit`, which is the result of a `pd.read_csv()` function.

```
datetime    B18_LR_T    B18_B1_T
24/03/2016 09:00    21.274  21.179
24/03/2016 10:00    19.987  19.868
24/03/2016 11:00    21.632  21.417
24/03/2016 12:00    26.285  24.779
24/03/2016 13:00    26.897  24.779
```

I am resampling the dataframe to calculate the 5th and 05th percentiles with the code:

```
keys_actual = list(t_unit.columns.values)

for key in keys_actual:
    ts_wk = t_unit[key].resample('W-MON')
    ts_wk_05p = ts_wk.apply(lambda x: x.quantile(0.05)).round(decimals=1).rename(key+'_05p', inplace=True)
    ts_wk_95p = ts_wk.apply(lambda x: x.quantile(0.95)).round(decimals=1).rename(key+'_95p', inplace=True)
```

All works fine, but when I add a column to my dataframe, by means of `pd.concat`, into:

```
datetime    B18_LR_T    B18_B1_T    ext_T
24/03/2016 09:00    21.274  21.179  6.9
24/03/2016 10:00    19.987  19.868  7.5
24/03/2016 11:00    21.632  21.417  9.1
24/03/2016 12:00    26.285  24.779  9.9
24/03/2016 13:00    26.897  24.779  9.2
```

> ts_wk_05p = ts_wk.apply(lambda x: x.quantile(0.05)).round(decimals=1).rename(key+'_05p', inplace=True)
>
> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: What is `key`? There's a part of your code you're not showing?

Comment: apologies, there are parts of the code I did not include to keep the question simple. Key now added

Comment: Here is an mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for that TypeError: `'a'*1.0`.  The traceback tells you the line where you do the equivalent.  Use a debugger or add a print statement just before to fine the actual value of the sequence and float.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy cannot see the mcve for that TypeError.

My traceback spots the 
`File "C:/ENVIDA/_code/T1_wk-mo_stats.py", line 82, in <lambda>

    ts_wk_05p = ts_wk.apply(lambda x: x.quantile(0.05)).round(decimals=1).rename(key+'_05p', inplace=True)
  
File "C:\Users\andrea.botti\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1343, in quantile
    dropna=True)`
Could it depend on the fact the the column `ext_T` has some missing data (whereas the other don't)?

Comment: Edit your question to include the full traceback.  When analyzing it, keep in mind that the traceback only includes the last physical line of logical lines that span multiple physical lines.  `dropna=True)` is obviously a continuation line (in function `quantile`, and the error must be somewhere above it.  "Could it depend...?"  Perhaps, but find the flagged expression first.

Answer (score 14):

There is problem some column is not numeric.
You can check [`dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html):

```
print (t_unit.dtypes)
B18_LR_T    float64
B18_B1_T    float64
ext_T        object
dtype: object
```

Then try convert to numeric first by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
t_unit.ext_T = t_unit.ext_T.astype(float)
```

If:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float

then use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert bad data to `NaN`:

```
t_unit.ext_T = pd.to_numeric(t_unit.ext_T, errors='coerce')
```

All code:

```
#simulate string column
t_unit.ext_T = t_unit.ext_T.astype(str)
print (t_unit.dtypes)
B18_LR_T    float64
B18_B1_T    float64
ext_T        object
dtype: object

#convert to float
t_unit.ext_T = t_unit.ext_T.astype(float)

print (t_unit)

L = []
for key in t_unit.columns:
    ts_wk = t_unit[key].resample('W-MON')
    #remove inplace=True
    ts_wk_05p = ts_wk.apply(lambda x: x.quantile(0.05)).round(decimals=1).rename(key+'_05p')
    ts_wk_95p = ts_wk.apply(lambda x: x.quantile(0.95)).round(decimals=1).rename(key+'_95p') 
    L.append(ts_wk_05p)
    L.append(ts_wk_95p)


print (pd.concat(L, axis=1))
            B18_LR_T_05p  B18_LR_T_95p  B18_B1_T_05p  B18_B1_T_95p  ext_T_05p  \
datetime                                                                        
2016-03-28          20.2          26.8          20.1          24.8        7.0   

            ext_T_95p  
datetime               
2016-03-28        9.8
```

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/21771133/2536029 for how to find the offending rows